How can I ensure that all line weights are adjusted at once?
I have linked a Geo section to my site where the routes of my trips are listed. In most cases, the polygons are clustered in groups of a day, which in turn consist of various (colored) line segments, for example for walking, transport by car, bus, train, boat, etc.
Each polyline has a line thickness (weight) of 4. In the map layer menu I have created an option to adjust the thickness. However, it only responds to the last read polyline of the last group (day).
See for example: Exemple map
The example consists of a total of 79 line segments divided over 20 groups (days).
How can I ensure that all line weights are adjusted at once?
Codes
Slider adjust line thickness
"<?php printf($Extralaag1) ?><input id='rangeCtrl' type='range' min='1' max='10' step='1' value='4' title='weight' width='20px' onchange='SetupPolylineOptions(this.value)' />": {<?php printf($Ovlmap1) ?>},

$Ovlmap1 = A collection (Kind of Array) of all days including the line segments.
Function that should adjust the line thickness
function SetupPolylineOptions(value) {
var pw = value;
if (pw == ""){
        pw = 4;
};
polyline.setStyle({weight: pw});
//polyline_options.setStyle({weight: value});

};

